# Python selenium error while loading browser data options

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver

I'm working on a project with python selenium 4.12.0 and having a problem with loading browser data through options

This is my code

```py
option = webdriver.EdgeOptions()
option.add_argument(f"user-data-dir=C:\\Users\\{os.environ.get('username')}\\AppData\\Local\\Microsoft\\Edge\\User Data")

browser = webdriver.Edge(options=option)
browser.get("https://web.whatsapp.com")
sleep(100)
browser.close()
```

and when I run this code it opens a browser window and all extenstions and bookmarks are loaded, but right before visiting the website (WhatsApp web) the program crashes with this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "d:\\WorkSpace\\Automation Projects\\Session-Reminder\\Schedule&SendMsg\\account_registry.py", line 16, in \<module\>
main()
File "d:\\WorkSpace\\Automation Projects\\Session-Reminder\\Schedule&SendMsg\\account_registry.py", line 10, in main
browser = webdriver.Edge(options=option)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "D:\\WorkSpace\\Automation Projects\\Session-Reminder\\venv\\Lib\\site-packages\\selenium\\webdriver\\edge\\webdriver.py", line 45, in __init__
super().__init__(
File "D:\\WorkSpace\\Automation Projects\\Session-Reminder\\venv\\Lib\\site-packages\\selenium\\webdriver\\chromium\\webdriver.py", line 56, in __init__
super().__init__(
File "D:\\WorkSpace\\Automation Projects\\Session-Reminder\\venv\\Lib\\site-packages\\selenium\\webdriver\\remote\\webdriver.py", line 205, in __init__
self.start_session(capabilities)
File "D:\\WorkSpace\\Automation Projects\\Session-Reminder\\venv\\Lib\\site-packages\\selenium\\webdriver\\remote\\webdriver.py", line 289, in start_session
response = self.execute(Command.NEW_SESSION, caps)\["value"\]
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "D:\\WorkSpace\\Automation Projects\\Session-Reminder\\venv\\Lib\\site-packages\\selenium\\webdriver\\remote\\webdriver.py", line 344, in execute
self.error_handler.check_response(response)
File "D:\\WorkSpace\\Automation Projects\\Session-Reminder\\venv\\Lib\\site-packages\\selenium\\webdriver\\remote\\errorhandler.py", line 229, in check_response
raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: msedge failed to start: exited normally.
(unknown error: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist)
(The process started from msedge location C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft\\Edge\\Application\\msedge.exe is no longer running, so msedgedriver is assuming that msedge has
crashed.)
Stacktrace:
GetHandleVerifier \[0x00007FF6F4803DB2+61490\]
Microsoft::Applications::Events::EventProperty::\~EventProperty \[0x00007FF6F4796002+740642\]
(No symbol) \[0x00007FF6F456B8AE\]
(No symbol) \[0x00007FF6F459CBFE\]
(No symbol) \[0x00007FF6F4597F13\]
(No symbol) \[0x00007FF6F45DB7F8\]
(No symbol) \[0x00007FF6F45D36E3\]
(No symbol) \[0x00007FF6F45A5EAA\]
(No symbol) \[0x00007FF6F45A518B\]
(No symbol) \[0x00007FF6F45A6634\]
Microsoft::Applications::Events::ILogManager::DispatchEventBroadcast \[0x00007FF6F49C8D69+1207369\]
(No symbol) \[0x00007FF6F4625304\]
Microsoft::Applications::Events::EventProperty::\~EventProperty \[0x00007FF6F46E90F1+32273\]
Microsoft::Applications::Events::EventProperty::\~EventProperty \[0x00007FF6F46E19E9+1801\]
Microsoft::Applications::Events::ILogManager::DispatchEventBroadcast \[0x00007FF6F49C7944+1202212\]
Microsoft::Applications::Events::ILogConfiguration::operator\* \[0x00007FF6F479E998+19784\]
Microsoft::Applications::Events::ILogConfiguration::operator\* \[0x00007FF6F479AE54+4612\]
Microsoft::Applications::Events::ILogConfiguration::operator\* \[0x00007FF6F479AF86+4918\]
Microsoft::Applications::Events::EventProperty::\~EventProperty \[0x00007FF6F478F451+713073\]
```

I think this error is coming from EdgeOptions() but still no idea how to fix it
I also tried to search a lot and found that this code snippet used to work on older versions of selenium but now it does not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `\\Default` at the end as below:

```
option.add_argument(f"user-data-dir=C:\\Users\\{os.environ.get('username')}\\AppData\\Local\\Microsoft\\Edge\\User Data\\Default")
```